# Firebase Query (Getting with child child property)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on Android with Firebase.
I have problems on querying to get objects with child of child property.
I attached my data structure.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDcJh.png]

I want to get groups that contains users with certain UserID.

Comment: For this Structure You have to use nested queries First Run Query for Event Change listeners in which you will read keys then go for reading child profile or users the add check if its profile then use Query for single event listener profile and if its not profile then run query for users. and then read its childrens.! Child(snapshot.gtKey()).child(object.getType()"Profile").addSingleEventValue‌​Listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to use denormalization which means that you need to create another node named `userGroups` in which you need to add all the groups of a specific user. You database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    ---- userGroups
             |
             --- userId1
             |      |
             |      --- groups
             |            |
             |            --- groupId1: true
             |            |
             |            --- groupId2: true
             |
             --- userId2
                    |
                    --- groups
                          |
                          --- groupId3: true
                          |
                          --- groupId4: true
```

With this database structure you can get all the groups in which a user is apart. Just attach a listener on the desired user and get all the groups from the `dataSnapshot` object.

Comment: Yes, you need to add that new node that solves your problem.